# Programmatically Obtain Hardware Details of a Node

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Is there a way to obtain hardware information (e.g. number of CPU cores, capacity of RAM) of an OpenShift 3.0 node programmatically? I could not find anything useful in the API references for [OpenShift](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/rest_api/openshift_v1.html) or [Kubernetes](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/rest_api/kubernetes_v1.html#v1-nodesysteminfo) (except for `NodeSystemInfo` in the Kubernetes API, which does not contain most of the hardware-level specs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a readonly stat endpoint exposed on both Openshift and Kubernetes. Normally it is exposed as https://api-host:10250/stats

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes `NodeStatus` has a field called `Capacity`, which is a list of resources with their corresponding amounts.

You can also see the Capacity in the output of `kubectl describe nodes`

e.g.

```
$ kubectl describe nodes my-node-1
Name:           my-node-1
...
Capacity:
 cpu:       1
 memory:    3801020Ki
 pods:      110
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to obtain the current resource usage (e.g. amount of used/free memory) via the API?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the allocated requests/limits directly from the node object. `kubectl describe` lists all pods scheduled to the node, and sums their associated resource requests: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/describe.go#L1582